# H2OTypeError: Argument `x` should be a None | integer | string | ModelBase | list(string | integer) | set(integer | string), got H2OFrame

Tags: python, data-science, h2o

I working with the Titanic dataset and made some basic preprocessing (such as normalization, ohe, etc.).

Then, I tried to use H2O algorithm and got following error:

```
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
classifier  =  H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds =    5,
                                            ntrees =   15,
                                            seed   =    42,
                                            max_depth = 4)

classifier.train(predictors, target, training_frame = train_data)
```

> H2OTypeError: Argument `x` should be a None | integer | string |
> ModelBase | list(string | integer) | set(integer | string), got
> H2OFrame

My target is `train_data["Survived"].asfactor()`

I tried to read to dataframe from file, instead of coverting the preprocessed df into H2OFrame but to no vail.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are passing frame instead of list of column names.
Both `x` and `y` are supposed to be "pointers" to columns in the `training_frame`.

If you want to use all columns as predictors (all except the target), you can specify just the `y` parameter.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```py
train_data["Survived"] = train_data["Survived"].asfactor()
classifier  =  H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds =    5,
                                            ntrees =   15,
                                            seed   =    42,
                                            max_depth = 4)

classifier.train(x=["pclass", "sex", "age",  ...], y="Survived", training_frame = train_data)
```